# How can I reference a YAML "setting" from elsewhere in the same YAML file?

Tags: syntax, yaml, template-engine, transclusion

I have the following YAML content:

```
paths:
  patha: /path/to/root/a
  pathb: /path/to/root/b
  pathc: /path/to/root/c
```

How can I "normalise" this, by removing `/path/to/root/` from the three paths, and have it as its own setting, something like:

```
paths:
  root: /path/to/root/
  patha: *root* + a
  pathb: *root* + b
  pathc: *root* + c
```

Obviously that's invalid; I just made it up. What's the real syntax? Can it be done?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620747/42223

Comment: See also: The YAML specs: https://yaml.org/spec/

Answer (score 205, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. You can reuse "node" but not part of it.

```
bill-to: &id001
    given  : Chris
    family : Dumars
ship-to: *id001
```

This is perfectly valid YAML and fields `given` and `family` are reused in `ship-to` block. You can reuse a scalar node the same way but there's no way you can change what's inside and add that last part of a path to it from inside YAML.

If repetition bother you that much I suggest to make your application aware of `root` property and add it to every path that looks relative not absolute.

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah ill have to prepend the `root` in code. no biggie.

Comment: The accepted answer is not accurate.  See my answer for a solution.

Comment: how to do this, if **bill-to** is in another file, which we have imported where  **ship-to** is defined ?

Comment: @PrateekJain: if you are dealing with multiple files, you will probably do best to evaluate a standalone YAML-enhancement library, such as one listed here. https://github.com/dreftymac/dynamic.yaml/blob/master/research.md#yaml-enhancement-libraries-and-modules-similar-or-alternative-approaches

Comment: See example 2.9 in http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html ; one can also reference scalars which is awesome

Answer (score 108):

Yes, using custom tags.  Example in Python, making the `!join` tag join strings in an array:

```python
import yaml

## define custom tag handler
def join(loader, node):
    seq = loader.construct_sequence(node)
    return ''.join([str(i) for i in seq])

## register the tag handler
yaml.add_constructor('!join', join)

## using your sample data
yaml.load("""
paths:
    root: &BASE /path/to/root/
    patha: !join [*BASE, a]
    pathb: !join [*BASE, b]
    pathc: !join [*BASE, c]
""")
```

Which results in:

```
{
    'paths': {
        'patha': '/path/to/root/a',
        'pathb': '/path/to/root/b',
        'pathc': '/path/to/root/c',
        'root': '/path/to/root/'
     }
}
```

The array of arguments to `!join` can have any number of elements of any data type, as long as they can be converted to string, so `!join [*a, "/", *b, "/", *c]` does what you would expect.

Comment: I like your solution, simpler in coding then mine at the cost of slightly less readable YAML.

Comment: The highlight over the down-arrow says "this answer is not useful" and that is essentially the case for anyone not interested in the subject of YAML. Even worse nobody (apart from me, because I was the only commenter so far) will get a notification of your comment/question. Chances that someone who downvoted comes back here and reads your comment and answers are so low that I would consider those close to non-existent. Having said that, it wasn't me, and if I were you I wouldn't ask and delete the comment.

Comment: Thanks! This works even to create a list with previously defined elements

Comment: This answer deserves more up-votes. It is technically the most accurate answer pursuant to the YAML specification. There is one caveat, however, pursuant to actual YAML *implementations*,  there are few that actually implement the full YAML spec. Python's pyyaml is above and beyond many others in terms of its uniformity with the specification.

Comment: The question seems to be about referencing a value IN a yaml file.  Adding another layer of code around it would not be my preferred solution.

Comment: There is no other way.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Thanks for this answer, I was wondering if you had a reference document that listed this syntax. I've seen YAML spec explained in multiple places on the web so I just want to make sure I'm looking at the same reference you are. Thanks!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me (`python3`?) however with a simple modification to the above it works as expected. Specifically:
`yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(tag='!join', constructor=join)`
`yaml.load(open(fpth, mode='r'), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)`

Answer (score 33):

Another way to look at this is to simply use another field.

```
paths:
  root_path: &root
     val: /path/to/root/
  patha: &a
    root_path: *root
    rel_path: a
  pathb: &b
    root_path: *root
    rel_path: b
  pathc: &c
    root_path: *root
    rel_path: c
```

Answer (score 8):

I've create a library, available on Packagist, that performs this function:
https://packagist.org/packages/grasmash/yaml-expander

Example YAML file:

```
type: book
book:
  title: Dune
  author: Frank Herbert
  copyright: ${book.author} 1965
  protaganist: ${characters.0.name}
  media:
    - hardcover
characters:
  - name: Paul Atreides
    occupation: Kwisatz Haderach
    aliases:
      - Usul
      - Muad'Dib
      - The Preacher
  - name: Duncan Idaho
    occupation: Swordmaster
summary: ${book.title} by ${book.author}
product-name: ${${type}.title}
```

Example logic:

```
// Parse a yaml string directly, expanding internal property references.
$yaml_string = file_get_contents("dune.yml");
$expanded = \Grasmash\YamlExpander\Expander::parse($yaml_string);
print_r($expanded);
```

Resultant array:

```
array (
  'type' => 'book',
  'book' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Dune',
    'author' => 'Frank Herbert',
    'copyright' => 'Frank Herbert 1965',
    'protaganist' => 'Paul Atreides',
    'media' => 
    array (
      0 => 'hardcover',
    ),
  ),
  'characters' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Paul Atreides',
      'occupation' => 'Kwisatz Haderach',
      'aliases' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Usul',
        1 => 'Muad\'Dib',
        2 => 'The Preacher',
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Duncan Idaho',
      'occupation' => 'Swordmaster',
    ),
  ),
  'summary' => 'Dune by Frank Herbert',
);
```

Comment: What is that? JSON?

Answer (score 5):

In some languages, you can use an alternative  library, For example, [tampax](https://github.com/arthurlacoste/tampax) is an implementation of YAML handling variables:

```js
const tampax = require('tampax');

const yamlString = `
dude:
  name: Arthur
weapon:
  favorite: Excalibur
  useless: knife
sentence: "{{dude.name}} use {{weapon.favorite}}. The goal is {{goal}}."`;

const r = tampax.yamlParseString(yamlString, { goal: 'to kill Mordred' });
console.log(r.sentence);

// output : "Arthur use Excalibur. The goal is to kill Mordred."
```

Editor's Note: poster is also the author of this package.

Answer (score 4):

**YML definition:**

```
dir:
  default: /home/data/in/
  proj1: ${dir.default}p1
  proj2: ${dir.default}p2
  proj3: ${dir.default}p3
```

**Somewhere in thymeleaf**

```
<p th:utext='${@environment.getProperty("dir.default")}' />
<p th:utext='${@environment.getProperty("dir.proj1")}' />
```

**Output:**
/home/data/in/
/home/data/in/p1

Comment: @AndrewBullock I think this should be the accepted answer, as it exactly solves your issue.

Comment: No, it is not a native usage of variable in YAML and it's not specified in any specification versions. After some test, this doesn't work.

Comment: This probably worked for Pavol using something that pre-processed the yaml (i.e. maven-resources-plugin filtering)

Comment: Not standard Yaml

Answer (score 3):

With [Yglu](https://yglu.io), you can write your example as:

```
paths:
  root: /path/to/root/
  patha: !? .paths.root + a
  pathb: !? .paths.root + b
  pathc: !? .paths.root + c
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of Yglu.

Comment: It's good to be aware of a library that adds this functionality on top of YAML

Comment: Thanks for making this. YAML is all the rage these days and it's nice to see a project to help contain the madness.

Answer (score 3):

## Using OmegaConf

OmegaConf is a YAML-based hierarchical configuration system that has support for this under the functionality [Variable interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.2_branch/usage.html#variable-interpolation). Using OmegaConf v2.2.2:

Create a YAML file `paths.yaml` as follows:

```yaml
paths:
  root: /path/to/root/
  patha: ${.root}a
  pathb: ${.root}b
  pathc: ${.root}c
```

then we can read the file with variable paths:

```py
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
conf = OmegaConf.load("test_paths.yaml")

>>> conf.paths.root
'/path/to/root/'

>>> conf.paths.patha
'/path/to/root/a'
>>> conf.paths.pathb
'/path/to/root/b'
>>> conf.paths.pathc
'/path/to/root/c'
```

### Deep and Cross -Ref

It is possible to define more complex (nested) structures with a relative depth of your variable in reference to other variables:

Create another file `nested_paths.yaml`:

```yaml
data:
    base: data
    sub_dir_A:
        name: a
        # here we note that `base` is two levels above this variable
        # hence we will use `..base` two dots but the `name` variable is
        # at the same level hence a single dot `.name`
        nested_dir: ${..base}/sub_dir/${.name}/last_dir 
    sub_dir_B:
        # add another level of depth
        - name: b
          # due to another level of depth, we have to use three dots
          # to access `base` variable as `...base`
          nested_file: ${...base}/sub_dir/${.name}/dirs.txt
        - name: c
          # we can also make cross-references to other variables
          cross_ref_dir: ${...sub_dir_A.nested_dir}/${.name}
```

again we can check:

```py
conf = OmegaConf.load("nested_paths.yaml")

# 1-level of depth reference
>>> conf.data.sub_dir_A.nested_dir
'data/sub_dir/a/last_dir'

# 2-levels of depth reference
>>> conf.data.sub_dir_B[0].nested_file
'data/sub_dir/b/dirs.txt'

# cross-reference example
>>> conf.data.sub_dir_B[1].cross_ref_dir
'data/sub_dir/a/last_dir/c'
```

In case of invalid references (such as wrong depth, wrong variable name), OmegaConf will throw an error `omegaconf.errors.InterpolationResolutionError`. It is also used in [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/simple_cli/) for configuring complex applications.

Answer (score 2):

That your example is invalid is **only** because you chose a reserved character to start your scalars with. If you replace the `*` with some other non-reserved character (I tend to use non-ASCII characters for that as they are seldom used as part of some specification), you end up with perfectly legal YAML:

```yaml
paths:
  root: /path/to/root/
  patha: ♦root♦ + a
  pathb: ♦root♦ + b
  pathc: ♦root♦ + c
```

This will load into the standard representation for mappings in the language your parser uses and does not magically expand anything.
To do that use a locally default object type as in the following Python program:

```python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import print_function

import ruamel.yaml as yaml

class Paths:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.d).replace('ordereddict', 'Paths')

    @staticmethod
    def __yaml_in__(loader, data):
        result = Paths()
        loader.construct_mapping(data, result.d)
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def __yaml_out__(dumper, self):
        return dumper.represent_mapping('!Paths', self.d)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        res = self.d[key]
        return self.expand(res)

    def expand(self, res):
        try:
            before, rest = res.split(u'♦', 1)
            kw, rest = rest.split(u'♦ +', 1)
            rest = rest.lstrip() # strip any spaces after "+"
            # the lookup will throw the correct keyerror if kw is not found
            # recursive call expand() on the tail if there are multiple
            # parts to replace
            return before + self.d[kw] + self.expand(rest)
        except ValueError:
            return res

yaml_str = """\
paths: !Paths
  root: /path/to/root/
  patha: ♦root♦ + a
  pathb: ♦root♦ + b
  pathc: ♦root♦ + c
"""

loader = yaml.RoundTripLoader
loader.add_constructor('!Paths', Paths.__yaml_in__)

paths = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)['paths']

for k in ['root', 'pathc']:
    print(u'{} -> {}'.format(k, paths[k]))
```

which will print:

```
root -> /path/to/root/
pathc -> /path/to/root/c
```

The expanding is done on the fly and handles nested definitions, but you have to be careful about not invoking infinite recursion.

By specifying the dumper, you can dump the original YAML from the data loaded in, because of the on-the-fly expansion:

```python
dumper = yaml.RoundTripDumper
dumper.add_representer(Paths, Paths.__yaml_out__)
print(yaml.dump(paths, Dumper=dumper, allow_unicode=True))
```

This will change the mapping key ordering. If that is a problem, you have to make `self.d` a `CommentedMap` (imported from `ruamel.yaml.comments.py`).

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own library on Python to expand variables being loaded from directories with a hierarchy like:

```
/root
 |
 +- /proj1
     |
     +- config.yaml
     |
     +- /proj2
         |
         +- config.yaml
         |
         ... and so on ...
```

The key difference here is that the expansion must be applied only after all the `config.yaml` files is loaded, where the variables from the next file can override the variables from the previous, so the pseudocode should look like this:

```
env = YamlEnv()
env.load('/root/proj1/config.yaml')
env.load('/root/proj1/proj2/config.yaml')
...
env.expand()
```

As an additional option the `xonsh` script can export the resulting variables into environment variables (see the `yaml_update_global_vars` function).

The scripts:

https://github.com/andry81/tacklelib/tree/HEAD/python/cmdoplib/cmdoplib.yaml.xsh
https://github.com/andry81/tacklelib/tree/HEAD/python/tacklelib/tacklelib.yaml.py

**Pros**:

- simple, does not support recursion and nested variables
- can replace an undefined variable to a placeholder (`${MYUNDEFINEDVAR}` -> `*$/{MYUNDEFINEDVAR}`)
- can expand a reference from environment variable (`${env:MYVAR}`)
- can replace all `\\` to `/` in a path variable (`${env:MYVAR:path}`)

**Cons**:

- does not support nested variables, so can not expand values in nested dictionaries (something like `${MYSCOPE.MYVAR}` is not implemented)
- does not detect expansion recursion, including recursion after a placeholder put