# Set global variables inside a Jekyll template

Tags: compilation, global-variables, jekyll

I have the following defined in my Jekyll config matter:

```
dir: a-directory/
```

I now want to have:

```
dir: a-directory/
images: {{ dir }}images/
```

However this won't work. One solution is to place this in my template file

```
{% capture images %}{{ site.dir }}images/{% endcapture %}
```

The variable images is now available to other points in that file. However it isn't available to any content being compiled in with that file, e.g my actual pages.

Doing `{% capture site.images %}` would seem the way to sort that, but you can't assign items to the `site` or `page` globals outside of the _config and front matter respectively.

Is it possible to achive this kind of global variable stacking?

*(please avoid solutions involving changing my directory structure; if there are similar compilers offering more features without a huge change to workflow I'm open)*

Answer (score 1):

---

It seems YAML doesn't directly support concatenation. There are a few workarounds, though:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212524
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22236941