# initializing yaml module in __init__.py

Tags: python, yaml, package, pyyaml

I'm using PyYAML, and would like to be able to use a string-concatenating constructor in my .yaml files.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212524/399397) shows how to add such constructors to PyYAML:

```
import yaml

## define custom tag handler
def join(loader, node):
    seq = loader.construct_sequence(node)
    return ''.join([str(i) for i in seq])

## register the tag handler
yaml.add_constructor('!join', join)
```

The above works when I enter it in a python terminal. However, I want to put the above in `my_package`'s `__init__.py` file, so that I can do:

```
from my_package import yaml  # my_package.__init__.py contains the above code

yaml.load("""
user_dir: &DIR /home/user
user_pics: !join [*DIR, /pics]
""")
```

However, this crashes with the message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1107dafdb1d2> in <module>()
----> 1 import simplelearn.yaml

/home/mkg/projects/simplelearn/simplelearn/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 import yaml
      2 
      3 def __join(loader, node):
      4     '''
      5     Concatenates a sequence of strings.

/home/mkg/projects/simplelearn/simplelearn/yaml.pyc in <module>()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_constructor'
```

What's going on? Why can't python find `yaml.add_constructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loading the module `yaml` from the file:

```
/home/mkg/projects/simplelearn/simplelearn/yaml.pyc
```

You either named one of your own files `yaml.py`, or you did have that file
before and renamed it, but forgot to remove the `yaml.pyc`. So you are not loading the PyYAML interpreter with `import yaml`.

The easiest way to verify is to include a temporary line after the `import`:

```
import yaml
print(yaml.__file__)
```

you **should** see something like `.../site-packages/yaml/__init__.pyc`.