# Spring Boot - extend yml configuration with custom yml tags

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I need to use yaml anchor references together with string concatenation inside `application.yml` for Spring Boot app. Motivation is to reuse existing configs and not duplicate them.
For example, we have the following `application.yml`:

```
sources:
  - filter:
      expression: &mainFilter
                    level > 100
  - filter:
      expression: *mainFilter
  - filter:
      expression: *mainFilter and level < 200
```

I need that it will be resolved to the following:

```
sources:
  - filter:
      expression: &mainFilter
                    level > 100
  - filter:
      expression: level > 100
  - filter:
      expression: level > 100 and level < 200
```

`expression: *mainFilter` will be resolved correctly as it's yml anchors, but `expression: *mainFilter and level < 200` will not work as yml doesn't support anchors with concatenation (app will fail on app start). According to [yml string concatenation with custom tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212524/2335775), yml has notion as custom tags that we could define, like `expression: !concat [*mainFilter, 'and level < 200']`. Is it possible to define and register our own custom tags in  Spring Boot yml configuration?

Comment: Why don't you make expression a collection?

Comment: in our case, `expression` field might have mathematical expressions, or OR and AND conditions, so collection doesn't fit

Comment: or and and shouldn't be a problem at all

Comment: @Clijsters please provide example with collection field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same need -- composing new property values from existing property values -- and after first thinking like you that it requires custom tags, in spring you can use [property placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders) instead:

```
mainFilter: "level > 100"
sources:
  - filter:
      expression: ${mainFilter}
  - filter:
      expression: "${mainFilter} and level < 200"
```