# Interpolate one YML scalar in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Trying to DRY up my en.yml for i18n:

```
en:
  phone: 800-123-4678

  errors:
    please_call: Please call 800-123-4678
    please_call2: Please call 800-123-4678 if you need assistance
```

Is there a way to reference a previously defined scalar and interpolate in another?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
en:
  phone: 800-123-4678

  errors:
    please_call: Please call <%= phone %>
    please_call2: Please call <%= phone %> if you need assistance
```

Didn't try it but found [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150782/using-yaml-with-variables) that says it should work. Try it out :)

Comment: Your syntax might require scope, but it would require loading the yml differently. I've updated my question to specify this is to be used for Rails i18n which gets loaded normally...