# Change <TEST> in a yaml file python

Tags: python, tags, yaml

I have to replace tags like these  in a yaml file.
The data that used to be replaced is stored in a list.
I have this YAML file

```
vagrantfile:    
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x<BITS> # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x<BITS> # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: <virtualiser>  # MEERKEUZE: virtualbox OF vmware, STANDAARD 64
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        use_linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_7orc03npv15g:
                        id: <ID> # STRING
                        hostname: <HOSTNAME> # STRING
                        network:
                            private_network: <IP-ADDRESS> #lOKAAL IP, STANDARAARD 192.168.50.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                hon1d:
                                    host: '80'
                                    guest: '80'
                        memory: '<MEGABYTES>' # AANTAL, STANDAARD VEELVOUD VAN 1024
                        cpus: '<CORES>' # AANTAL CPUS, STANDAARD AANTAL CORES - 1, NIET HOGER DAN AANTAL CORES
```

What can I do to change al these tags?

Comment: Is the data stored in a list or in a dict?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 1):

You should do this at the level of YAML, just to make sure that if your substitution forces the resulting string to be quoted that this actually happens. E.g. if your `<ID>` needs to be replaces by something like `@abc` the actual line in the YAML file needs to become

```
id: '@abc'
```

and not

```
id: '@abc'
```

as `@` is reserved. There are several such caveats, so substituting on the string level is not a good idea.

You can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x<BITS> # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x<BITS> # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: <virtualiser>  # MEERKEUZE: virtualbox OF vmware, STANDAARD 64
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        use_linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_7orc03npv15g:
                        id: <ID> # STRING
                        hostname: <HOSTNAME> # STRING
                        network:
                            private_network: <IP-ADDRESS> #lOKAAL IP, STANDARAARD 192.168.50.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                hon1d:
                                    host: '80'
                                    guest: '80'
                        memory: '<MEGABYTES>' # AANTAL, STANDAARD VEELVOUD VAN 1024
                        cpus: '<CORES>' # AANTAL CPUS, STANDAARD AANTAL CORES - 1, NIET HOGER DAN AANTAL CORES
"""


def replace(data, values):
    def do_one(data, values):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for k in data:
                data[k] = do_one(data[k], values)
            return data
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            for idx, elem in enumerate(data):
                data[idx] = do_one(elem, values)
            return data
        elif isinstance(data, str):
            for k in values:  # full match
                if data == k:
                    return values[k]
            if '<' in data and '>' in data:
                for k in values:
                    data = data.replace(k, str(values[k]))
                return data


    expanded = { ('<' + k + '>'): v for (k, v) in values.iteritems()}
    do_one(data, expanded)

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)

replace(data, {
    'BITS': 64,
    'virtualiser': 'virtualbox',
    'HOSTNAME': 'localhost',
    'IP-ADDRESS': '192.168.0.1',
    'ID': '@abc',
    'MEGABYTES': 2048,
    'CORES': 8,
    })

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, stream=sys.stdout, indent=4)
```

which will give you:

```
vagrantfile:
    target:
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64     # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64     # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_version:
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox     # MEERKEUZE: virtualbox OF vmware, STANDAARD 64
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1:
                        showgui:
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus:
                    parallels:
                        use_linked_clone:
                        check_guest_tools:
                        update_guest_tools:
                machines:
                    vflm_7orc03npv15g:
                        id: '@abc' # STRING
                        hostname: localhost  # STRING
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.0.1  #lOKAAL IP, STANDARAARD 192.168.50.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                hon1d:
                                    host:
                                    guest:
                        memory: 2048          # AANTAL, STANDAARD VEELVOUD VAN 1024
                        cpus: 8         # AANTAL CPUS, STANDAARD AANTAL CORES - 1, NIET HOGER DAN AANTAL CORES
```

Please note that:

- the comments are preserved
- that the value for `cpus` and `memory` are integers, not strings
- that the value for `id` gets properly quoted as necessary.

The above uses [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/): disclaimer I am the author of that package. You can do the same with PyYAML, but you will lose the comments and you need to restrict yourself to the YAML 1.1 standard (from 2005) and not the YAML 1.2 standard (from 2009)

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to use pyyaml. E.g. to set the `cpus` value:

```
import yaml
foo = yaml.load(open('file.yml', 'r'))
foo['vagrantfile']['vm']['provider']['local']['machines']['vflm_7orc03npv15g']['memory'] = 'bar'
yaml.dump(foo, open('out.yml', 'w'))
```

Only issue is you'll lost the comments this way.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an option to iterate the file and replace the tags?

Comment: because i'm using python 2.7

Comment: Ah, I guess I didn't realise the tags were always going to be the same.  In that case I'd go with something like gipsy's solution with a string template (i'd personally use curly braces and `.format`).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the yaml into a string template and use string formatting to achieve this

```
template = """vagrantfile:    
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x%(BITS)s # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x%(BITS)s # MEERKEUZE: 32 OF 64, STANDAARD 64
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: %(virtualiser)s  # MEERKEUZE: virtualbox OF vmware, STANDAARD 64
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        use_linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_7orc03npv15g:
                        id: %(ID)s # STRING
                        hostname: %(OSTNAME)s # STRING
                        network:
                            private_network: %(IP-ADDRESS)s #lOKAAL IP, STANDARAARD 192.168.50.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                hon1d:
                                    host: '80'
                                    guest: '80'
                        memory: '%(MEGABYTES)s' # AANTAL, STANDAARD VEELVOUD VAN 1024
                        cpus: '%(CORES)s' # AANTAL CPUS, STANDAARD AANTAL CORES - 1, NIET HOGER DAN AANTAL CORES"""


replaced = template % {"BITS": "some value", "virtualiser": "something", "ID": 2412, "OSTNAME": "OS name", "IP-ADDRESS": "some ip", "MEGABYTES": 100, "CORES": 16}
```

Comment: Depending on the values that you substitute this can result in output that cannot be parsed by a YAML parser.