# Curly braces in a YAML file

Tags: yaml, travis-ci

I've found the following [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/flaiker/ci-cfg-templates/blob/master/travis-ci/libgdx.travis.yml) template.

I've noticed this:

```
    repo: {GITHUB_USER}/{PROJECT_NAME}
```

Is this a special `.yml` variable syntax I'm not familiar with? Where can I set these values (`GITHUB_USER`, `PROJECT_NAME`)?

---

I know I can use environment variables, like so:

```
    repo: $GITHUB_USER/$PROJECT_NAME
```

but this syntax looks different.

Comment: practically every YAML parser I know complains about this. Curly braces in YAML stand for a flow style mapping and must be quoted if they are meant literal. I guess this YAML file is preprocessed, and those are template placeholders, so the final YAML file will be valid

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905103/yaml-reusable-variables-with-case-specific-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a valid YAML file. After the first `}` the YAML parser will expect a block style continuation. This means either a key that aligns with `repo` or outdenting. Instead it finds a `/` and any YAML parser should throw an error on that.

This looks like a template for a YAML file, e.g. using something like the following in Python after loading the contents of the file in string `templ`:

```
templ.format(**dict(GITHUB_USER="Janez", PROJECT_NAME="test"))
```

On the other hand the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` for many more years than Travis exists, so maybe that is why they used the `.yml` extension.