# Repeat node value in YAML

Tags: yaml

```
pagination:
    limit:
        default: 10
        min: 0
        max: 50
        current: default
```

The `current` node should have the same value as the `default` node? (in this case, 10). Is it possible to do that with YAML?

Comment: yes. that's an amazing feature in yaml which beats xml and json

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777987/string-interpolation-in-yaml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an [anchor](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586) for that, which is a token starting with `&` inserted before the scalar/mapping/sequence you want to "re-use". You "paste" it with an alias which is the same token preceded by a `*`.

```
pagination:
    limit:
        default: &def 10
        min: 0
        max: 50
        current: *def
```

(you can use `default` instead of `def` but you don't have to use the same string as the key whose value you put an anchor on)