# How to concat strings in application.yaml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, development-environment

I want to add two lines in a yaml file, or rather, I want the instance-id field to contain the result of adding the values of the port and name fields
I tried using +, tried through various tags that I saw in similar questions, like !join, !concat (java says they don't exist). But nothing worked in the end.
Is there a solution?

Example yaml (Sorry, i dont know how to load yaml here):

```html
server:
  port: &port 62000
spring:
  application:
    name: &appname 'appname'
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: 'http://localhost:8081/eureka/'
  instance:
    instance-id: here should be *appname + ":" + *port (result appname:62000)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String interpolation in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777987/string-interpolation-in-yaml)

Comment: This is an application.yaml for spring boot, I assume? Maybe update the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work for YAML in general, but it will work in Spring Boot, since you can use [Property Placeholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders), and thus reference other properties from within a property value:

```
server:
  port: 62000
spring:
  application:
    name: 'appname'
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: 'http://localhost:8081/eureka/'
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}
```

This also works with environment variables, btw.

Comment: Hi!
I tried it - it didn't work, but then, apparently, my application did not perceive my application file as an application file (the settings were not read from there)
I renamed the file and put it in the resource root and everything worked. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i can provide my application.yml file config for flyway, i think that, based on this code, you can achieve what you want

```html
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}
    user: ${DATABASE_USER}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    enabled: true
    validate-on-migrate: true
    baseline-version: 0
    default-schema: ${DATABASE_SCHEMA}
```

and you should remember, that this values must been provided by you, while running application, put them in a environment variables see [a link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/add-environment-variables-and-program-arguments.html#add-environment-variables)!, or if you run integration tests, you can use `@DynamicPropertySource public static void setUpDynamicPropertyValues(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) { // registry.add("eureka.instance.instance-id", () -> "your instance-id here");`

Answer (score 1):

typically we don't have direct string concatenation or arithmetic operations like in some other languages. However, you can use YAML anchors and aliases to achieve something similar.