# How to set parameters to yaml file in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

There is a yaml file in a Rails application which named 'notices.yml'.

```
notices:
  content: "Notice 1."
```

Now want to set the notice content to dynamatic as:

```
  content: "Notice 1. Good"
```

So should parse parameter to it in some logic.

I have thought about Rails' `I18n`. If use something like `I18n.t("notices.content", "Good")` may realize it. The yaml should be:

```
notices:
  content: "Notice 1. %{data}"
```

But how to make the method? I am using a way to read yaml file like:

```
# config/application.rb
config.notices = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/notices.yml")
```

```
# Some controller
content = Rails.configuration.notices['notices']['content']
```

It seems difficult to set parameter like that way.

I checked the `I18n`'s `translate` method:

> https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n.rb#L179

It use `**options` to set data. I have no idea to make a simple way to realize this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20467816