# How to create dynamic YAML string

Tags: python, yaml, templating, string-interpolation

I have a YAML file

```
tests:
  - is-gt: val, 2
    info: "Test Succeeded!!, val is greater than 2, it is <{{post['val']}}>"
    err: "Test Failed!!, val is not greater than 2, it is <{{post['val']}}>"
```

in this case, instead of hard coding value of val(i.e. 2 ), it should directly take value specified with operation "is-gt".
If I change test operation to " is-gt: val, 3" , it should automatically take this value inside info and error message.

How do I do this? I am using this YAML file further in some Python script to read it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just yaml. Tools that let you do that actually post-process the values using, for instance Jinja or `template.Template`. Here for instance you could make the value you test against available as a template variable, under name "value" for instance, and just put `{{value}}` in your string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do string substitution in Yaml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407488/is-it-possible-to-do-string-substitution-in-yaml)

Comment: @spectras can you tell me how is it possible using Jinja ? I am new to this if you can elaborate with an example

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 1):

Your `is-gt` is just a scalar string to YAML, that functions as a key for a mapping. There is nothing special about that string, and it is certainly not an "operation".

You can post-process your loaded YAML (e.g. if you use `safe_load` from ruamel.yaml/PyYAML). What is cleaner YAML, is that you tag your sequence items and, based on that tag, load your mapping key/values into a specific object that interprets `is-gt` and updates the scalar strings of the other values that become its attributes.

Such an object would best have a map-like interface and you would have to decide to do the resolving at load time, or using lazy evaluation when retrieving the values by its key.

Answer (score 1):

YAML is a data serialization language, not a data processing language. Templating capabilities are beyond its scope (although there exist a few optional features in that direction, which are not applicable here).

Postprocessing with other templating languages has already been proposed. I'd like to add the suggestion to use [pystache](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache) because it is a minimal language which might be more appropriate here than using Jinja.

Furthermore, I'd suggest to put the value spec into a map. And since you already use `{{` for something else in the string, I'd suggest to tell pystache to use another means of escaping. Example:

```
tests:
  - is-gt: {val: 2}
    info: "Test Succeeded!!, val is greater than `val`, it is <{{post['val']}}>"
    err: "Test Failed!!, val is not greater than `val`, it is <{{post['val']}}>"
```

You can now parse it like this:

```
import yaml, pystache

raw = yaml.safe_load("""
tests:
  - is-gt: {val: 2}
    info: "Test Succeeded!!, val is greater than `val`, it is <{{post['val']}}>"
    err: "Test Failed!!, val is not greater than `val`, it is <{{post['val']}}>"
""")

def dynString(inputs, template):
    return pystache.render("{{=` `=}}" + template, inputs)

tests = []
for rawtest in raw["tests"]:
    test = {}
    inputs = rawtest["is-gt"]
    for msg in ["info", "err"]:
        test[msg] = dynString(inputs, rawtest[msg])
    tests.append(test)

print(tests)
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'info': "Test Succeeded!!, val is greater than 2, it is <{{post['val']}}>",
  'err': "Test Failed!!, val is not greater than 2, it is <{{post['val']}}>"}]
```

Comment: You still have `post['val']` in your output. On first glance I think you have to populate `post` instead of `inputs`, but I haven't used `pystache` (so I might be wrong).

Comment: Anthon: I believe that this is what is wanted, because `post['val']` accesses the actual value that is compared, while `{val: 2}` specifies the value to be compared against. But I might be wrong, it is not very clear from the question. It was asked how to replace the `2` with the value given in the YAML, which I did.

Comment: I missed the substitution of `2` by `val` in your separate input, probably because you still use the hardcoded 2 in the multiline string that you actually `safe_load()` instead of using the backquoted `val`. If you change `2` → `3` in `is-gt`'s value nothing happened.

Comment: Oh yes, I oversaw that. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: @flyx thanks for solution but what if {val: 2} is {//val :2} and as remaining `val`

Comment: @YashAwasthi I do not really get what you're asking. `{//val :2}` does parse as `{"//val :2": ""}` because of missing space after `:`, so that cannot work. But if you have `{//val: 2}`, you can use `//val` as template variable.