# Notepad++: Replace find query with words from list

Tags: regex, text, replace, find, notepad++

I would like to replace all "var_"

```
var_
   Hello
var_
   Whats
var_
   Up?
...
```

with words from this list

```
alpha
beta
gamma
...
```

so the end result is

```
alpha
   Hello
beta
   Whats
gamma
   Up?
...
```

Would appreciate help on achieving this!

Comment: Please show us some of your attempted code. And possibly make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Can you provide your real situation? The example that you showed doesn't help much.

Comment: I have edited the original question to make it clearer hopefully.

Comment: If you wanna replace each **_var** for each words from a list, you should use a procedural language, to use a foreach, for example.

Comment: Which language are you planning working on it?

Comment: @EdilsonBorges How would you use "foreach" for this? I am working in YAML.

Comment: Can't be done with YAML (foreach), may be this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407488/is-it-possible-to-do-string-substitution-in-yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of impossible / overly complicated with a regex. However, if you combine it with a programming language, you can get it done quickly. E.g. in python it would look like this:

```
import sys
import re
import fileinput

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
  exit("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " <filename> <replacements>")

input_file = sys.argv[1]
replacements = sys.argv[2:]
num_of_replacements = len(replacements)
replacement_index = 0
searcher = re.compile("^var_\\b")

for line in fileinput.input(input_file, inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
  match = searcher.match(line)
  if match is None:
    print(line.rstrip())
  else:
    print(re.sub("^var_\\b", line.rstrip(), replacements[replacement_index]))
    replacement_index = replacement_index + 1
```

Usage: `replacer.py ExampleInput.txt alpha beta gamma`

#### Update

It's possible to modify the program to accept the string you search for as the 1st param:

```
replacer.py "var_" ExampleInput.txt alpha beta gamma
```

The modified python script looks like this:

```
import sys
import re
import fileinput

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
  exit("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " <pattern> <filename> <replacements>")

search = "\\b" + sys.argv[1] + "\\b"
input_file = sys.argv[2]
replacements = sys.argv[3:]
num_of_replacements = len(replacements)
replacement_index = 0
searcher = re.compile(search)

for line in fileinput.input(input_file, inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
  match = searcher.match(line)
  if match is None:
    print(line.rstrip())
  else:
    print(re.sub(search, line.rstrip(), replacements[replacement_index]))
    replacement_index = replacement_index + 1
```

**Note:** this script still has a few limitations:

- it expects that the string you search for occurs only once each line.
- it replaces the searched string only if it's a distinct word
- you can accidentally incorporate any python regex syntax into the `search` param

Comment: Is it possible to add the text to be replaced into the command?

For example:
`replacer.py "var_" ExampleInput.txt alpha beta gamma`

Comment: Yes, you can allocate one more sys.argv param for that. In this case `search = sys.argv[1]`, `input_file = sys.argv[2]` and `replacements = sys.argv[3:]`. You'll need to rewrite the command params check at the beginning, i.e. `if len(sys.argv) < 4: ...`. The search would be `searcher = re.compile("^"+search+"\\b")`. The replacement would be `re.sub("^"+search+"\\b", line.rstrip(), ...)`