# how to use internal reference in a yml file

Tags: syntax, yaml

i hava a yml-file like this:

```
jvm_config: 
  tomcat_port: 1066
  jvm_opts: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10667"
```

and want to have something like this.

```
jvm_config: 
  tomcat_port: 1066
  jvm_opts: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${tomcat_port}7"
```

in xml it works but how to do in yml?

Comment: PyYAML can load this (so I expect that libyaml works). What are you using to parse it? Or did you want the value of tomcat_port to be substituted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to reference a yaml "setting" from elsewhere in the same yaml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file)

Comment: See my answer - simple approach that uses YAML custom tags - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23212501/763269