# Optimizating application.yml file in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have some constants in application.yml file which I am using in my application at different places.

Example ( In my config/application.yml)

```
 main_url : "http://abc.net/api"
     a_url: "http://abc.net/api/a"
     b_url: "http://abc.net/api/b"
     c_url: "http://abc.net/api/c"
```

looking into this code the URL "http://abc.net/api" is repeating at every place. I want to remove repeating URL and use main_url + rest url combination. How to do this in application.yml I want my application.yml should look like

```
main_url : "http://abc.net/api"
     a_url: main_url + "/a"
     b_url: main_url + "/b"
     c_url: main_url + "/c"
```

What is the best way to remove repeated code from your configuration YAML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. You can reuse "node" but not part of it.

```
bill-to: &id001
    given  : Chris
    family : Dumars
ship-to: *id001
```

This is perfectly valid YAML and fields `given` and `family` are reused in `ship-to` block. You can reuse a scalar node the same way but there's no way you can change what's inside and add that last part of a path to it from inside YAML.

If repetition bother you that much I suggest to make your application aware of `root` property and add it to every path that looks relative not absolute.

source: [how to reference a YAML "setting" from elsewhere in the same YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file)