# YAML reference another variable in another file

Tags: string, reference, yaml, transclusion

Suppose I have 2 YAML files:

1) application.yml

```
en:
  variable: "Hello World"
```

2) user.yml

```
en:
  variable: <Here I want to get value from application.yml -> "Hello World" >
```

At first I though that I might use referencing:

1) application.yml

```
en:
  variable: &variable "Hello World"
```

2) user.yml

```
en:
  variable: *variable
```

But turned out that it is only possible for items declared in one file.
Is there any way I can get the value from the variable defined in application.yml ?

Comment: No, I don't think YAML can do this.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski Thank you for your answer.
So the only way is to create another, third file that would hold shared values? Or to use the value from "application.yml"? Right?

Comment: Correct! YAML references are intra-file. You could also have a preprocessing step where you merge YAML files.

Comment: OK then. Just as I suspected. Thank you!

Comment: This is technically possible under YAML Tag semantics. You would have to create a custom tag. See e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23212501/42223

Answer (score 9):

> So the only way is to create another, third file that would hold shared values.
>   Or to use the value from "application.yml".
>
> YAML references are intra-file.
>
> You could also have a preprocessing step where you merge YAML files.

In *nix shell:

```
cat foo.yaml bar.yaml > baz.yaml
```

In Powershell:

```
cat foo.yaml, bar.yaml > baz.yaml
```

In batch:

```
type foo.yaml bar.yaml > baz.yaml
```

**References**

- [Look Ma, No Tags!](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1005)
- [Powershell cmdlets: get-content](http://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [cat](http://ss64.com/bash/cat.html)
- [COPY Concatenates Files Based on Command Syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69575)

Comment: Thanks, @Paul Sweatte!
Can you, btw, show how would you merge YAML files. How to run this preprocessing?
Thanks again!

Comment: I've added some ways to merge using various languages.