# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Configuration Questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Alright, so I get you can define environment variables within an `environment.config` file in the `.ebextensions` folder.

But let's say I want the AWS Account ID to be available as an environment variable here. Is there a way to dynamically retrieve that value given the context in which the Elastic BeanStalk application is deployed?

Also is there a way to refer to other environment variables within the config file? For example, given we're working within `.ebextensions/environment.config`:

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
  foo: '123'
  bar: hello-${foo}
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated here, thanks!

Comment: So I don't think my latter suggestion is allowed. I believe it's a strict mapping from the onset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html), the `aws sts get-caller-identity` command can be used to retrieve the AWS Account ID.

Regarding your second question, I believe `.config` files are in YAML format, which would mean that you cannot reuse a value as part of another value. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file) for more information.