# YAML how to reuse single string content

Tags: yaml

Lets suppose I've this

```
a: "ABC"
b: *a
```

I want `b` to have the same content than `a`, keep in mind that a is an string, not an array.

is this possible?

Comment: YAML is just a data format, but having said that, you can always use a query format like JsonPath or http://yaql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html to refer to another property or even an external value like an ENV or a property from a properties file. I've seen stuff like that in Azure Container Instances JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reference a YAML "setting" from elsewhere in the same YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate, yes, but this question is more clearly trying to reuse a single string. I was glad to find it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, that's called an alias.
You make an Anchor with `&anchorname` and refer to it with `*anchorname`

```
a: &a "ABC"
b: *a
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use an array to define many aliases which is quite succinct.

```
aliases:
  - &foo "foo"
  - &bar "bar"
test1: *foo
test2: *bar
```