# Reference parameter within the params block

Tags: r, quarto

I use the params block in the quarto header to manually set variables when testing a report. It would be nice to be able to refer to a parameter when defining the value of another parameter. I want the parameters to be independent when calling `quarto render`, so I don't want to do this within the report code.

Instead of this:

```
---
params:
  base: ~/a/long/path
  file1: ~/a/long/path/file1.txt
  file2: ~/a/long/path/file1.txt
---
```

Can I do something like this?

```
---
params:
  base: ~/a/long/path
  file1: $base/file1.txt
  file2: $base/file1.txt
---
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible as YAML doesn't support concatenation. You could write a Quarto filter to parse the YAML, like in this [Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063616/how-to-reference-a-yaml-setting-from-elsewhere-in-the-same-yaml-file) but that would probably be overkill. Are you using the params in R code? Can you do the interpolation there, e.g. lose the path from the file names and do `file1 <- sprintf("%s/%s",  params$base, params$file1)`?